# android - How to close an activity on button click?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want a button click to close an Activity. I am new to intents and and a little confused.
This is `ActivityOne` which keeps a track of life cycle. 
On a button press, it opens `ActivityTwo` and puts `ActivityOne` in background.
This works fine when I used this intent in my `onClickListener`:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
ActivityOne.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

In `ActivityTwo` I need to use intents and `finish()` method to close the activity. I tried to Google it and I thought this might work:

```
Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);
ActivityTwo.this.finish(myIntent2);
```

---

It didn't work the full code is below:

```
public class ActivityOne extends Activity {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);

        // ...

        Button launchActivityTwoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLaunchActivityTwo); 
        launchActivityTwoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO:
                // Launch Activity Two
                // Hint: use Context's startActivity() method

                // Create an intent stating which Activity you would like to start
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);

                // Launch the Activity using the intent
                ActivityOne.this.startActivity(myIntent);               
            }
        });

        // ...
    }
}
```

---

**Activity 2:**

```
public class ActivityTwo extends Activity {    

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

        // ...

        Button closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClose); 
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO:
                // This function closes Activity Two
                // Hint: use Context's finish() method
                Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);
                ActivityTwo.this.finish(myIntent2);
            }
        });
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: pressing back button will close your activity.

Comment: Of course that pressing back button will close it, but that is not the question! :)

Comment: for ActivityOne I just put ` startActivity(intent); ` and it works fine, no need to type className.this.startActivity(intent);  If anyone knows of a reason I need to write it out like the questioner feel free to chip in.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You want to close `ActivityTwo` when a button is clicked? Just use `finish();`

Full code for the button listener in `ActivityTwo` would be:

```
Button closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClose); 
closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO:
        // This function closes Activity Two
        // Hint: use Context's finish() method
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

@Arjun Krishnan you want to kill activityTwo?

try this

```
 ActivityTwo.this.finish();
```

It would help you

Answer (score 4):

Alright the best way to finish the ***current Activity*** is by using `finish()` method. So inside the `onClick()` of your button in the `ActivityTwo` you can do this.

```
closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            //closes ActivityTwo
        }
});
```

**no need to make new intents for finishing current Activity**. Also note that *pressing back* will also finish your Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Replace these two lines

`Intent myIntent2=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTwo.class);
                ActivityTwo.this.finish(myIntent2);`

with this 
                `ActivityTwo.this.finish();`

Answer (score 1):

```
Button exit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.yes);
exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
```