# VideoView - Android Activity Close

Tags: android, android-studio, video, android-activity, android-videoview

In Full Screen Activity Android, OnBack pressed activity is not getting closed. Can Anyone help provide the solution? I have used on back pressed. Still unable to close the activity.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
       finish()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android - How to close an activity on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473509/android-how-to-close-an-activity-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```